# Passing class into iPython Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

I'm trying to pass a class into iPython for parallel execution. As it is, this code runs, but it loads 'Timezone' each time. This class requires about 10s per load, so this overhead is unacceptable, unless it happens only once, or once per core.
I'm very new to parallelization, and I would like to know now to move the imports out of the function. At least I think that is the correct approach.

```
from IPython import parallel
clients = parallel.Client()
lview = clients.load_balanced_view()

lview.block = True

lats = [32.21, 34.98]
lons = [109.45, -102.4]
times = ['2014-03-12T16:20:44.000000000Z', '2014-03-12T15:48:52.000000000Z']

@lview.parallel()
def f(lats, lons, times):
    import sys,os
    sys.path.append("../utils/") # For grabbing 'Timezone'

    import Timezone as Timezone
    tz = Timezone.Timezone()

    # Use tz to compute local time
    a = tz.compute_local_time(lats, lons, times)

    return a

%time f.map(lats, lons, times)
```

Results in:

```
in sync results <function __call__ at 0x105d2db18>
CPU times: user 700 ms, sys: 232 ms, total: 932 ms
Wall time: 11.6 s
Out[15]:
[('Asia/Chongqing', '2014-03-13 00:20:44'),
 ('America/Chicago', '2014-03-12 10:48:52')]
```

The results double in time (around 22 seconds) if I double the length of the input data.
How can I pass in `tz` and have each core call the `Timezone` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's how I did it.
First, I used a direct view and loaded the module(s) onto each core, then I used `scatter` and `gather` to break up the input, finally using `map` to access the array/list inputs.

```
from IPython import parallel
from IPython import parallel as p

rc = p.Client()
rc[:].execute('import sys,os')
rc[:].execute('sys.path.append("../utils/")')
rc[:].execute('import Timezone as Timezone; tz = Timezone.Timezone()')

dview = rc[:] # A DirectView of all engines
dview.block = True
```

In the next cell:

```
def f(v, lats, lons, times):
    v.scatter('lat', lats)
    v.scatter('lon', lons)
    v.scatter('time', times)
    v.execute("D=map(tz.compute_local_time, lat, lon, time)")
    return v.gather('D', block=True)

lats = [32.21]
lons = [109.45]
times = ['2014-03-12T16:20:44.000000000Z']

%time r = f(dview, lats, lons, times)
```

This gave me the output I wanted and was about twice faster than just using:

```
map(tz.compute_local_time, lat, lon, time)
```